# Pre-populate partial cache in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I have a Rails application where I have configured partial caching to cache all the slow changing parts of my home page.

The cache entries are set to automatically expire after an hour.

Is there any way in which I can get my Rails app to repopulate the partial cache itself, instead of waiting for the first user to hit the page once the cache elements have expired?

Thanks for any help